# Export Marketing Cloud Journey Data to Salesforce Sales

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have numerous Journey version since we have made changes throughout the year so having a nice single dashboard showing all the email metrics of the Journey is not possible unless I am missing something.  So what I am wondering is, can I export the SFMC data(clicks,opens,bounces,...) to the SFSC environment?  The goal would be to consolidate all the version of a specific Journey into a single reports/graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will note that when configuring an Email Activity in a Journey Builder Interaction, there's an option to Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud (refer to screenshot below). I have yet to use this feature, but I assume this will only work if you are using a 'Salesforce Data' event or 'Salesforce Campaign Event' from the Define Entry Event modal when creating an entry event.

This feature is undocumented, but I assume that it enables you to review tracking data for each email in Salesforce, similar to the current functionality with Salesforce Email Sends.

[image: tracking results to Sales Cloud]

Comment: Eliot, Thank you for your answer.  I am going to select the 'Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud' after I determine that it will not effect the current active Journeys or I may need to create yet another version of the same Journey.  Thanks again.